# How do you retrieve only active users (that haven't been disabled) from Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, active-directory

I am using the code below to get the email of all users in Active Directory. However the code also returns users that have been disabled in Active Directory.

How do I filter the results to only return users that have an active account?

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://MyDomain");
DirectorySearcher dSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
dSearch.Filter = "(objectClass=user)";

foreach (SearchResult sResultSet in dSearch.FindAll())
{
    if (sResultSet.Properties["mail"].Count > 0)
        Response.Write(sResultSet.Properties["mail"][0].ToString() + "<br/>");
}
```

I think there may be an attribute in Active Directory that defines if the account is disabled or not and I could use this attribute to filter the results.

I am using C# .NET.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for enabled UserPrincipal 
   UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
   qbeUser.Enabled = true;

   // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
   PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

   List<string> emails = new List<string>();

   // find all matches
   foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
   {
       UserPrincipal foundUser = found as UserPrincipal;
       emails.Add(foundUser.EmailAddress);
   }
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.